# What establish a session?

Tags: oracle, query, session, powerbi

As an analyst I'm running multiple queries on our Oracle ERP via Power Query (Power BI). Now, I hit some form of session limit on my default profile's session limit. How do you evaluate how many sessions I use without accessing the Oracle database directly? Are they the number of tables you access in the FROM statements?

Error message:

> OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Oracle: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit.

Comment: Do you have an error message you can share?

Comment: "Sessions" would generally correspond to the number of network connections to the database. It would not have anything to do with the number of tables being queried. The number of network connections you are attempting will depend on how Power BI works internally, and is limited by your Oracle user profile in the database.

Comment: Error message is this @AnthonyGenovese:
OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] Oracle: ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit.

Comment: So what did you discover when you googled 'ORA-02391' ?